# SQL - get row for same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table.

```
select * from Group
```

```html
Owner    Member1   Member1_Value    Member2  Member2_Value
Kelly    Nicol         2             Julie       4
Nicol    Julie         4             Kelly       3
Julie    Kelly         5             Nicol       3
```

Now I need to get Avege value from our Members for Owners.

```html
Owner    Member1   Member1_Value    Member2  Member2_Value    Avg
Kelly    Nicol         2             Julie       5            3.5
Nicol    Julie         4             Kelly       2            2.5
Julie    Kelly         5             Nicol       3            4.5
```

Eg: Kelly's Avg 3.5 comes from  Nicol gave 2 and Julia gave 5 and Avg is 3.5.  as same as Nicol got Avg 2.5 because Kelly gave 2 and Julie gave 3.

So how can I get that Avg colum from one sql statment

Appreciate your answers

Thanks

Comment: `Nicol got Avg 2.5 because Kelly gave 2 and Julie gave 3.`, can't understand??

Comment: I need to get average value. It means 2+3/2 = 2.5, hope you cl ear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that what you want is this but you should consider normalising a little bit that table in order to be able to do this kinds of queries easier:

```
SELECT
   Name, AVG(Value) AS Value
FROM
(
    SELECT
       Member1 AS Name,
       Member1_Value As Value
    FROM Group
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       Member2 AS Name,
       Member2_Value As Value
    FROM Group
 ) Normalised
 GROUP BY Name
```

A better table structure for this will by

Member(MemberId, Name)
Group(GroupId)
GroupMember(MemberId, GroupId)
Qualifications(ProvidingMemberId, ReceivingMemberId, Value)

Or something similar

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly then it should work :

```
select *, cast((Member1_Value + Member2_Value) as Decimal(10,2))/2 [Avg] from Group
```

Comment: Hey Deepak, Thanks for your reply. This is survey data. so Kelly got reviews from Nicol and Julie. 

According to your sql I can get only average value which I gave to my member. But In here I need to get average value which I get from our member ?

I hope you are clear .

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very complicated data structure.  Normally, having columns like `member1` and `member2` is a sign of poor database design.  You should really normalize the table.

You seem to want the contribution of the *other* member from matching rows in the table.  I think the following does what you want:

```
select g.owner, (gm1.member2_value + gm2.member1_value) / 2.0
from group g join
     group gm1
     on g.owner = gm1.member1 join
     group gm2
     on g.owner = gm2.member2;
```